# How can I count the number of unique elements in an array using NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, arrays

I have a csv file with one particular column. This column has multiple rows, each row with an array comprising of multiple elements. Following are four sample rows in the csv file:

```
['Rose', 'Lily', 'Jasmine', 'Rose']

['Google', 'Microsoft', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Uber', 'Google']

['Norway', 'Norway', 'Norway']

[]
```

I want to count the number of **unique elements** in each row/array.

The output for the above four sample rows should be in an array as follows:

```
[3, 4, 1, 0]
```

Please note that the last row/array is null and hence has 0 elements in it.

---

This is my code so far:

```
const csv = require('csv-parser')
const fs = require('fs')
const results = [];

fs.createReadStream('filepath/filename.csv')
.pipe(csv())
.on('data', (data) => results.push(data))
.on('end', () => {

    var Column_Name = []

    for (var item in results) {
        Column_Name.push(results[item]["Column_Name"])
        console.log(countUnique(Column_Name))
        console.log('Column_Name'.length)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at [sets for javascript](https://medium.com/better-programming/an-introduction-to-sets-in-javascript-5bebaace3135#:~:text=Sets%20are%20a%20new%20object,array%20with%20no%20repeated%20elements). A set is a data structure that only allows unique elements, you could convert your array to a set and then count the elements in the set. Here is an example:

```
var arr = [55, 44, 65, 55];
var set = new Set(arr);
console.log(set.size === arr.length);
```

Comment: How can I apply this for a csv with multiple rows of arrays? Your approach seems to work for manual declaration of an array.